# How can I fix this web layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I have a web layout I have been working on today with one static column and one fluid column.

My problem is that the code suddenly broke (I'm not sure why) and it is now floating incorrectly.

My structure is this:

```
    <div class="side-wrap">
        <div class="side">
            <div class="side-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="brand"><a href="#">ProbabilityWolf</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span>&raquo;</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About<span>&raquo;</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact<span>&raquo;</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="page"> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am posting the CSS externally becuase there is quite a bit of it.
Here is my code (and the website): http://jsfiddle.net/QTbtA/

Since I am asking anyway, is there any way to improve my layout to make it work better? I am writing this out of my head, and I am a beginner when it comes to fluid layouts.

**EDIT: I have now resolved the problem, although tips would be appreciated.**

Comment: You can remove `float` and `margin` from `page-wrap` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right - it works for me in chrome if I remove `margin-right:400px` from your `.side-wrap` class.

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTbtA/1/). I hope it does what you want.